# How to do select all customers group by customer id?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongotemplate

My mongodb customer collection has the following fields:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("582577eebac0ef176a8d0697"),
    "customerID" : NumberLong(37620089),
    "storeID" : NumberLong(1),
    "updatedDate" : ISODate("2017-03-27T14:07:11.278Z"),
    "customerName" : "hsingla cust"
}
```

I want to run 2 queries which in SQL will look like:

`Select * from Customer group by customerID having storeID=1;`
`Select count(*) from Customer group by customerID having storeID=1;`

I am new to mongodb and I have read various articles but couldn't seem to get the right answer.

Also, I am using `mongoTemplate` in java, so it would help if you can give me a couple of queries using `mongoTemplate`.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: also, I want to use descending sort on updatedData and use pagination by using skip and limit

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap them into one aggregation query.

`push("$$ROOT")` as `customers` for the first part of the query and `count()` as count for the second part.

```
  TypedAggregation<Customers> agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(Customers.class,
            Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("storeID").is(1L)),
            Aggregation.group("customerID").
                    push("$$ROOT").as("customers").count().as("count"),
            Aggregation.unwind("customers"),
            Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "customers.updatedData"),
            Aggregation.skip(5L),
            Aggregation.limit(10));
   List<Customers> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "customer", Customers.class).getMappedResults();
```

More here `$$ROOT` - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#system-variables

Comment: Hey Veeram, 
Thanks.
There are a couple of other things though :-

How do I convert List<BasicDBObject> to List<Customers>, which has the model :-
{
    Long  customerID;
    Long storeID;
    Data updatedData;
    String customerName;
}

I am not able to convert _id even if I added _id in my model.

Comment: Also, I would like to sort the data which I get from mongo on updatedDate, and would also like to make my results paginated, using 'skip' and 'limit'. I would be very grateful if you can help me with this.

Comment: did the answer work for you ? Please consider accepting the answer.